# In Google's CTS, what does the script named cts-tradefed stand for?

Tags: android, android-testing, cts

I've just started working with Google's CTS and ran into a script that had very little explanation surrounding it- cts-tradefed. I've scoured the web and found a few resources that mention it such as the [CDD](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en/us/compatibility/4.1/android-4.1-cdd.pdf) and the [CTS manual](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en/us/compatibility/android-cts-manual-r5.pdf) but nowhere is it stated what it stands for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "Trade Federation"... you know, the [thing from *Star Wars*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_Federation). As for *why* it's called that? Who knows.

Comment: I never would have put that together, thank you. Do you have anything you can link to that confirms this? You know, just for when people laugh at me when I tell them a widely used CTS script stands for something out of Star Wars.

Comment: Yup! [The initial GIT commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/tradefederation/+/f72f44c5e47929edf8a0a104d988c8cbaa1d73cd).